# Why is primefaces 6.2 jar not backward compatible?

Tags: primefaces

We are using primefaces6.1 jar and we found lot of formatting issues with p:editor tag. In research we found that most of these issues will be fixed in primefaces6.2. While upgrading to primefaces6.2, there are lot of other tags got removed/replaced and we need to make lot of corrections in the code. Why there is no backward compatibility with primefaces6.2 jar?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is because software must always progress and sometimes there is no easy backwards compatibility without adding bloat.  PF 6.1 to 6.2 was major because it went from Jquery 1 to Jquery 3.  I suggest you read the [6.1 to 6.2 Migration Guide](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide#61-to-62).

We have been spoiled by languages like Java that have never removed any code since Java 1.  It becomes difficult to maintain for smaller development teams and is actually more cost effective to remove code than it is to maintain backwards compatibility.

Comment: I know you can't help it, but a major upgrate like jquery 1 to 3 should have been a major upgrade of PF to (7?)

Comment: @Kukeltje you are probably right.  PF seems to make some major decisions on minor releases.  Version numbers don't cost anything so why not just bump to a major if you are making a major change.

Comment: it does cost something... The latest 5.x branch needs maintenance, the 6.x and then the 7.x too. Dropping the 5.x is an option then

Comment: Yes it would have to mean that.  They don't have unlimited resources.  Support only the latest 2 Major releases without a PRO subscription.

Comment: And one additional community release (e.g. the 6.2.1 should be community one to with the most important bugfixes ;))